# Hide part of a picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this code (adapted from [pgfplot: Fill between while including decoration function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671424/pgfplot-fill-between-while-including-decoration-function)):

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671424/pgfplot-fill-between-while-including-decoration-function
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=center,
            xmin=0, xmax=12.5,
            ymin=0, ymax=15,
            ]
            \fill[blue!60] (7,7.8)--(8.3,7.8)--(7,9.5)--cycle;
            \draw[violet,line width=3pt] (7,7.5)--(7,10);
            \filldraw[brown!40,draw=blue,line width=2pt] (6,6.5)--(5.5,7.5)--(8.5,7.5)--(8,6.5)--cycle; 
            \node at (6.3,7.2) () {\tiny \LaTeX};
            \draw[name path=line] (0,0) -- (12,0);
            \addplot[
            name path=plot, 
            cyan,
            domain=0:12,
            preaction={decorate},
            samples=100,
        %   decoration={markings, mark=between positions 0.05 and 1 step (1/12)*\pgfdecoratedpathlength with {\arrow{latex}}}, % commenta questa linea se non vuoi le frecce                   
            ] {.1*sin(3*x*180/pi)+7};
            \addplot[fill=cyan!40] fill between[of=line and plot,overlay];
        \end{axis}    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that produce this output:

[image]

I want to to hide the part of the boat under the water. I tryed with `opaque`, `opacity=`,...,but no desired results.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506332/47927

Comment: I see it as a big mistake to use `fillbetween`. `fillbetween` is brilliant, but unfortunately overused in many cases, where it is not needed.

Comment: None of the answers hide the part under the water. Did you actually want that hidden?

Comment: @Simd Also partially hidden. Did you have a better solution?

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro I have no idea how to do it. I just noticed the answers didn't obviously fit the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been noted in [this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506332/47927), you need to set the layer for things drawn with the `fill between` operator.

The [manual explains](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/libs-fillbetween#sec-46.1)  that things drawn with the `fill between` operator are per default placed on a layer that sits "between the main layer and the background layer". So, you can use `fill between/on layer=main` to shift this to the layer where all the other things are drawn to. I'd also add `axis on top`:

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671424/pgfplot-fill-between-while-including-decoration-function
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=center,
            xmin=0, xmax=12.5,
            ymin=0, ymax=15,
            axis on top,
            fill between/on layer=main
        ]
            \fill[blue!60] (7,7.8) -- (8.3,7.8) -- (7,9.5) -- cycle;
            \draw[violet, line width=3pt] (7,7.5) -- (7,10);
            \filldraw[brown!40, draw=blue, line width=2pt] 
                (6,6.5) -- (5.5,7.5) -- (8.5,7.5) -- (8,6.5) -- cycle; 
            \node at (6.3,7.2) () {\tiny \LaTeX};
            \draw[name path=line] (0,0) -- (12,0);
            \addplot[
                name path=plot, 
                cyan,
                domain=0:12,
                preaction={decorate},
                samples=100,                
            ] {.1*sin(3*x*180/pi)+7};
            \addplot[fill=cyan!40, opacity=0.5] fill between [of=line and plot];
        \end{axis}    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I have tryed, like,you, with opacity=.2, but no changes.

Comment: I see the difference: 'fill between/on layer=main'. Bravo.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Yes, this is the key key (so to say). However, this is in fact kind of a dupe of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506332/47927, don't you think? Well, at least it is related ...

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
axis on top,
xmin=0, xmax=12.5,
ymin=0, ymax=15,
]
\fill[blue!60] (7,7.8) -- (8.3,7.8) -- (7,9.5) --cycle;
\draw[violet, line width=3pt] (7,7.5) -- (7,10);
\filldraw[blue, fill=brown!40, line width=2pt] (6,6.5) -- (5.5,7.5) -- (8.5,7.5) -- (8,6.5) --cycle; 
\node at (6.3,7.2) {\tiny \LaTeX};
\fill[cyan!40, opacity=0.5] plot[domain=0:12, smooth] (\x,{.1*sin(3*\x*180/pi)+7}) |- (current axis.south) -|cycle;
\draw[cyan] plot[domain=0:12, smooth] (\x,{.1*sin(3*\x*180/pi)+7});
\end{axis}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with water and a boat]

```
\draw[cyan] plot[domain=0:12.18, samples=100, smooth, variable=\t] ({\t+.2*cos(\t*180-180)},{.3*sin(\t*180-120)+7});
```

[image: Graph with wavy water and a boat]